# What causes Openshift v3 slow to load?

Tags: ssl, openshift, cloudflare, cname

I deploy a little app for some websites (Laravel with domain routing actually) in Openshift Online 3 free, and set some routes to it accordingly. And I make use of Cloudflare for the DNS server. In the Cloudflare, I set to use strict SSL. The domains are set to redirect to CNAME of Openshift default route.

The problem is, the websites are quite slow to load, as I install custom SSL certificate from Cloudflare into Openshift's route. So, what makes it so slow, actually?

Comment: It is a known issue which is affecting the Online Starter environments on and off. You can track status of Starter environments at https://status.starter.openshift.com/ If you get into your container and from the shell use curl to make a request against the site at $HOSTNAME:8080, you should see that the response is quick. If it isn't then it is more likely to be an issue with your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried to curl from the container, and I got quick response.